Count with specific values in columns
I have here a small code for getting the total number of IDs with the status values, "Pending A" and "Pending B". This is my sheet below called Sheet1.

1201    Pending A
1202    In progress
1203    Pending A
1204    Pending B
1205    Pending C
1206    Pending B
1207    Pending B

This is the code I am trying to use for my desired output.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, count As Long, K As Long
        Dim arrData, arrList(), i As Long, j As Long
        Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        
        Set rng = ws.Range("A1:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        arrData = rng.Value
        
        count = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng.Columns(2), "Pending A" Or rng.Columns(2), "Pending B")
        ReDim arrList(1 To count + 1, 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
        
        For i = 2 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 2) = "Pending A" Or "Pending B" Then
                K = K + 1
                For j = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)
                    arrList(K, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
                    arrList(K, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
                Next
            End If
        
        Next
             
        With Me.ListBoxTrial
            .ColumnHeads = False
            .ColumnWidths = "30,30"
            .ColumnCount = UBound(arrData, 2)
            .List = arrList
        End With
        
        Label1.Caption = count
End Sub

I am getting an error saying this below with no yellow mark.

This is my desired output.

Please advise. TY

What do you try to calculate here: ""Pending A" Or rng.Columns(2)"?

i would like to get the total number of IDs that has Pending A and Pending B

No, no. Exactly this expression: ""Pending A" Or rng.Columns(2)". You try to apply OR to the string and the range. First, this expression is calculated by VBA not by formula. Second, it's completely wrong.

First try to enter the desired formula onto worksheet to get it operational and correct. Then use the formula text in the code.

@rotabor will try

Another way is to use the Application.Evaluate method. It allows you to use a native formula rather than WorksheetFunction which requires arguments calculated in VBA.

im quite new but i will study the method ty

Why use WorksheetFunction.CountIfs? K-1 is the value you are looking for.

Use a Collection to Count and Hold the Matching Row Numbers
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        
    ' Define constants.
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 2
    
    ' Return the values of the range in an array.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rng As Range:
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:B" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    Dim sRowsCount As Long: sRowsCount = rng.Rows.Count
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = rng.Columns.Count
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = rng.Value
    
    ' Return the matching source row numbers in a collection.
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection
    Dim sr As Long
    For sr = 2 To sRowsCount
        Select Case CStr(sData(sr, CRITERIA_COLUMN))
            Case "Pending A", "Pending B"
                coll.Add sr
        End Select
    Next sr
    
    ' Define the destination array
    Dim dRowsCount As Long: dRowsCount = coll.Count
    If dRowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no matches
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To dRowsCount, 1 To ColumnsCount)
    
    ' Loop through the items (matching source rows) of the collection
    ' to populate the destination array.
    Dim srItem As Variant, dr As Long, c As Long
    For Each srItem In coll
        dr = dr + 1
        For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
            dData(dr, c) = sData(srItem, c)
        Next c
    Next srItem
         
    ' Populate the listbox...
    With Me.ListBoxTrial
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ColumnWidths = "30,30"
        .ColumnCount = ColumnsCount
        .List = dData
    End With
    ' ... and the label.
    Label1.Caption = dRowsCount
        
End Sub

